# Weblogic 10 Managed servers running, but I get a 404 error

Tags: weblogic, weblogic-10.x

I have migrated an application from WL 8 to WL 10 and set up my managed servers.  They indicate that they are running, but when I try to access the site it throws a 404.  This is my first time deploying anything on 10 so I could be missing something.  Any ideas?   Please let me know what additional information could be helpful.  edit:  I had this working, added a db connection and now it fails.

Here is my error:

```
weblogic.management.DeploymentException: Exception occured while downloading files
        at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.datamanagement.AppDataUpdate.doDownload(AppDataUpdate.java:43)
        at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.datamanagement.DataUpdate.download(DataUpdate.java:56)
        at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.datamanagement.Data.prepareDataUpdate(Data.java:98)
        at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.BasicDeployment.prepareDataUpdate(BasicDeployment.java:670)
        at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.BasicDeployment.stageFilesForStatic(BasicDeployment.java:713)
        at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.AppDeployment.prepare(AppDeployment.java:100)
        at weblogic.management.deploy.internal.DeploymentAdapter$1.doPrepare(DeploymentAdapter.java:39)
        at weblogic.management.deploy.internal.DeploymentAdapter.prepare(DeploymentAdapter.java:187)
        at weblogic.management.deploy.internal.AppTransition$1.transitionApp(AppTransition.java:21)
        at weblogic.management.deploy.internal.ConfiguredDeployments.transitionApps(ConfiguredDeployments.java:233)
        at weblogic.management.deploy.internal.ConfiguredDeployments.prepare(ConfiguredDeployments.java:165)
        at weblogic.management.deploy.internal.ConfiguredDeployments.deploy(ConfiguredDeployments.java:122)
        at weblogic.management.deploy.internal.DeploymentServerService.resume(DeploymentServerService.java:173)
        at weblogic.management.deploy.internal.DeploymentServerService.start(DeploymentServerService.java:89)
        at weblogic.t3.srvr.SubsystemRequest.run(SubsystemRequest.java:64)
        at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:200)
        at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:172)
java.io.IOException: [DeploymentService:290066]Error occurred while downloading files from admin server for deployment request "0". Underlying error is: "[DeploymentService:290065]Deployment service servlet encountered an Exception while handling the deployment datatransfer message for request id "0" from server "TEST01". Exception is: "weblogic.management.configuration.JDBCSystemResourceMBeanImpl"."
        at weblogic.deploy.service.datatransferhandlers.HttpDataTransferHandler.getDataAsStream(HttpDataTransferHandler.java:86)
        at weblogic.deploy.service.datatransferhandlers.DataHandlerManager$RemoteDataTransferHandler.getDataAsStream(DataHandlerManager.java:153)
        at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.datamanagement.AppDataUpdate.doDownload(AppDataUpdate.java:39)
        at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.datamanagement.DataUpdate.download(DataUpdate.java:56)
        at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.datamanagement.Data.prepareDataUpdate(Data.java:98)
        at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.BasicDeployment.prepareDataUpdate(BasicDeployment.java:670)
        at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.BasicDeployment.stageFilesForStatic(BasicDeployment.java:713)
        at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.AppDeployment.prepare(AppDeployment.java:100)
        at weblogic.management.deploy.internal.DeploymentAdapter$1.doPrepare(DeploymentAdapter.java:39)
        at weblogic.management.deploy.internal.DeploymentAdapter.prepare(DeploymentAdapter.java:187)
        at weblogic.management.deploy.internal.AppTransition$1.transitionApp(AppTransition.java:21)
        at weblogic.management.deploy.internal.ConfiguredDeployments.transitionApps(ConfiguredDeployments.java:233)
        at weblogic.management.deploy.internal.ConfiguredDeployments.prepare(ConfiguredDeployments.java:165)
        at weblogic.management.deploy.internal.ConfiguredDeployments.deploy(ConfiguredDeployments.java:122)
        at weblogic.management.deploy.internal.DeploymentServerService.resume(DeploymentServerService.java:173)
        at weblogic.management.deploy.internal.DeploymentServerService.start(DeploymentServerService.java:89)
        at weblogic.t3.srvr.SubsystemRequest.run(SubsystemRequest.java:64)
        at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:200)
        at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:172)
```

Comment: Have you verified if everything is OK in your context-root in weblogic.xml?

Answer (score 1):

You got a `weblogic.management.DeploymentException` and this means that something went wrong in some server even if everything seems OK from the console.

Underlying error is from `weblogic.management.configuration.JDBCSystemResourceMBeanImpl` so I would review datasource config is appropiate for every target in your environment. Also check that datasource targets are the same as web application targets and JDBC drivers are available at managed servers classpath as well.

Answer (score 0):

Try to log to the WebLogic Admin console and see what is the status of your application.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the 'Testing' tab of your deployment to see the URL that the application has been deployed to.  This will assist you in the troubleshooting process.

[image: Testing Tab]

If you don't see anything here to test there are a few possible reasons, including the following:

1. The application failed to deploy and/or is not 'Active'
2. You are using a cluster and no managed servers are running
3. You have managed servers running but they are not in a 'RUNNING' state

Comment: I have nothing there to test, possibly because I'm not using a .war file?  Instead I pointed to a dir on the machine. I am using the startManagedWebLogic.sh script to start.  Weird thing is I was serving up pages and then added a DB connection and now i'm getting errors.  I'm wondering if this has something to do with staging, as my old machine had it set to "no stage" and the current one says "not specified".  I've added the error I am getting

Comment: What are you deploying - an EAR file?